# Почему вид страницы на responsive Desktop отличается от responsive Mobile

Tags: html, css

Делаю адаптив на странице и заметил одну вещь, которую я совсем не могу понять: у меня responsive mobile отличается от responsive desktop

Причем самая важная особенность состоит в том, что есть блок `.center-block`, который меняет свою ширину в зависимости от ширины экрана:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.center-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```

И тогда все выглядит нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я меняю на Mobile:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То все ломается, все блоки, которые находятся выше становятся в длину `980px` (непонятно для меня почему), ширина `.center-block`как будто перестает воспринимать ширину экрана и меняться и страница ломается

До этого у меня жестко тупил localhost и выдавал следующую ошибку:

```
Error: Manifest request to /_nuxt/0e62de9e27088d02f526.hot-update.json timed out. at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange
```

Не знаю насколько это взаимосвязано, но решил упомянуть

В чем проблема, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вангую, что надо дописать meta viewport в html https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, оказывается забыл на этой странице указать. Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

```
попробуй убрать screen and оставь:

@media (max-width: 767px)
.center-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```